# Questions About The Foundation And NS Library

Tags: objective-c, header, foundation, gnustep, nsobject

I'm a Objective-C learner and I don't have a Mac, then I need to use my Linux with GNUStep, but if I develop my own program on it, the end-user will need to have GNUStep(like .Net) installed and then I started thinking how can I solve this, then I had an idea: "Create this from scratch!", but now to do this I need to know: What are the most important things in NS and Foundation headers? Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend that you simply start with simpler projects to learn Objective-C than try to re-implement years of endeavors and efforts done by many Objective-C experts.

Answer (score 2):

notnoop makes an excellent point: Foundation is an extremely complex and well-tested framework; somewhere along the lines of 10 or 15 years in the making (someone will have to hit me with the precise date of inception).

Perhaps the single most important part of the Foundation framework is `NSObject`. The (sort of) single root class that all objects inherit from is one of the greatest strengths of *Step.

Implementing your own Obj-C root class should be an interesting exercise.

EDIT: I would be remiss if I did not mention a few of the other important features: Implementation-abstracted collection classes (`NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSSet`), strings (`NSString`), utility classes (`NSProcessInfo`, `NSUserDefaults`), serialization tools (`NSCoder`), ...

It's a comprehensive framework, to say the least.

Comment: 20 years would be more correct, with Objective-C getting close to 30.

Answer (score 1):

get started with **Programming in Objective-C 2.0**
written by **Stephen G. Kochan**

thats how i started it...